Uppy With Ajax page Load
I have a working install of uppy V2 and trying to migraet to V3. In the index.html page I have
<script src="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v3.17.0/uppy.min.js"></script>
Taken from docs migration guide.
I am loading content "docs" with an uppy div into index.html via ajax call. In docs I am init uppy with
const uppy =  new Uppy().use(Dashboard, { inline: true, target: '#uppy' });
Uppy is a valid object however this does not init and teh uppy dashbaord is not rendered. Any code lines after this are not executed. This is minimal configuration straight from the uppy documentation so I don't understand what is causing the problem. Anyone else seen this?
Thanks
Paul
I also tried loading up a via the module import script in the index page. Same problem
